# Как изменить useSWRMutation на useSWR

Tags: reactjs

У меня есть такой запрос

```
  const { data: jobsData, trigger: jobsTrigger } = useSWRMutation(
    formJobsUrl(
      sinceDate,
      currentPage,
      comment,
      authorName,
      instrument,
      userData.profile.email
    ),
    updateFetcher
  );
```

в useSWRMutation есть функция trigger в которую можно передать параметр и когда изменится этот параметр useSWRMutation отработает снова, стригерится и тогда мы получим новые данные. Мне нужно переписать useSWRMutation на просто useSWR, для того, чтобы испольщовать в нем refreshINterval, но какая функция мне заменит trigger, без триггера ничего не работает или может в useSWRMutation есть аналог refreshInterval ?